Minimum of Matrix norm over subspace.
Suppose that $U$ and $V$ are linear subspaces of $\mathbb{R}^{d}$ such that $U\cap V = \{0\}$ and let $A$ be an invertible Matrix. Then it holds that for $\eta_{1}=\max_{||x||=1,x\in U}||Ax||>$,  $\eta_{2}=\max_{||x||=1,x\in V}||Ax||$ and $\eta=\max_{||x||=1,x\in U\oplus V}||Ax||$ that $\eta\geq \max\{\eta_{1},\eta_{2}\}$. I suppose that something similar holds for the minima i.e
letting $\delta_{1}=\min_{||x||=1,x\in U}||Ax||>$,  $\delta_{2}=\min_{||x||=1,x\in V}||Ax||$ and $\delta=\min_{||x||=1,x\in U\oplus V}||Ax||$ is it true that $\delta\geq \min \{\delta_{1},\delta_{2}\}$? I tried to prove it by expanding for $x=u+v\in U\oplus V$ the term $||A(u+v)||^{2}$ but get stuck there.

No. The direction of the inequality should be reversed.
E.g. suppose that $U$ and $V$ be two one-dimensional subspaces spanned by two linearly independent unit vectors $u$ and $v$ respectively. Now let $x$ and $y$ be two linearly independent unit vectors. Define $Au=x$ and $Av=y$. Then $\delta_1=\delta_2=1$ but $\delta$ is close to zero when $x$ and $y$ are sufficiently close.
For a concrete counterexample, let $U=\operatorname{span}\{e_1\},\,V=\operatorname{span}\{e_2\}$ and $A=\pmatrix{1&\cos t\\ 0&\sin t}$ for some $t\approx 0$.
